# Sync my website with outlook and gmail calendars

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a web site (written in Ruby-on-Rails) which enable the users to create alert with content and time stamp (e.g. "meeting with my parents on 1/8/2013 14:00PM").

I want to be able to schedule them this meeting in their calendar (gmail, outlook, iPhone).
Is there a generic way for doing this? What is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Calendar [has an API](http://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar).

Hotmail Calendar [has an API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826535.aspx).

iCloud Calendar might have an API, I'm not sure. I think it uses CalDAV, but I'm not familiar with the details of how to interact with it.

There's really no generic way to interface with all of these services, you'd have to integrate to each one independently. (Even if they use the same or very similar protocols and standards, the token authorization for them will be different.)

Comment: Thanks,
I use CalDav for all of them (one way events publishing).